# Why fluorescence lifetime in laser crystals decreases while dopant concentrations increases?

Tags: optics, atomic-physics, laser, fluorescence

I noticed, that is laser crystals the low levels of doping are used and that if higher levels did, the lifetime of excited level will be shorter.

Why? The atoms of dopant are the same. Why do they live shorter if there are more of them?

Example: https://www.scientificmaterials.com/products/er-yag.php

Comment: Typically because of dopant-dopant interactions perturbing the lifetime of the states. Or more disorder in the crystal from too many dopants. Dopant clustering. Etc.

Answer (score 1):

*Since a laser expert hasn't answered yet, I'll take a stab with my general knowledge and some online research at RP-Photonics.com*

When pumping stops in a laser, the remaining excited ions take various amounts of time before they relax and release a photon (see [Radiative Lifetime](https://www.rp-photonics.com/radiative_lifetime.html)). It's an exponential decay, so you can think of it as a "half-life" of fluorescence, if that analogy helps.

In a low dopant crystal, dopant ions are preponderantly isolated from each other, multiple lattice cells apart, not interacting.

Whereas in a high dopant crystal, most of the dopant ions have one or more other dopant ions as their neighbors. They interact with each other, exchanging energy in various ways (see [Energy Transfer](https://www.rp-photonics.com/energy_transfer.html)). These interactions provide other ways for excited ions to relax, decreasing the fluorescence lifetime.

*How did I do?*

Comment: I came to conclusion, that doping makes levels wider. And wider means shorter lifetimes.